# when I click delete it will display this error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the sql error

```
SQL error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`motioncenter`.`news`, CONSTRAINT `news_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_categories_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`))
Line: 36
Fil: C:\Xampp\htdocs\xampp\site\admin\page_functions\category_delete.php
```

herre is the category_delete.php file
Line: 36 is echo format_error_message(mysqli_error($database_link), $query, **LINE**, **FILE**);

```
<?php
    if ( !isset($database_link))
    {
        die(header('location: index.php?page=categories'));
    }

    if ( !isset($_GET['category_id']))
    {
        die(header('location: index.php?page=categories'));
    }

    $category_id = ($_GET['category_id'] * 1);

    $query = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE category_id = $category_id";
    if (mysqli_query($database_link, $query))
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] .= 'deleted<br />';
        die(header('location: index.php?page=categories'));
    }
    else
    {
        echo format_error_message(mysqli_error($database_link), $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    }
?>
```

Comment: problem is in foreign keys in your database tables not in php code. so please provide your table structures.

Comment: Your categories table contains foreign keys. So you will have to delete all foreign data before deleting the category record.

Comment: in categories table there 3      category_id - category_title - category_description

Answer (score 1):

Probably your constraint that links items to category prevents you from deleting a category, while some items, news in your example, are still referencing it. Perhaps you should modify your foreign key constraint so that it does cascade delete, like `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Answer (score 0):

Your database contains foreign keys that have been configured such that you cannot delete categories if there are any news items in that category.

It's kind of like trying to `rm` a directory that has files in it, you'll get an error saying the directory is not empty.

Add a query to `"DELETE FROM news WHERE category_id=".$category_id` or update the news items to be in a different category before deleting the category itself.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a category_id from the category table leads to an error since category_id acts a foreign key in another table. By deleting a value in category_id, all the other instances of that value in other table that reference it will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first delete tables with a foreign key referenced to your categories table.
`motioncenter.news` table has `fk_categories_id` field with the value you are trying to delete. you need to either delete that row in news table first or use below sql statement to disable foreign checks alltogether.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you've to delete all news which is dependent on that category.
Then you can delete that category.

Or alternatively you can change constraint for foreign key:

```
# Table `motioncenter`.`news`
ALTER TABLE `motioncenter`.`news`
DROP FOREIGN KEY `news_ibfk_2`,
ADD CONSTRAINT `news_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_categories_id`)
REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Or if you want to keep all related news even then you should change to:

```
# Table `motioncenter`.`news`
ALTER TABLE `motioncenter`.`news`
DROP FOREIGN KEY `news_ibfk_2`,
ADD CONSTRAINT `news_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_categories_id`)
REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

> Because by default foreign key prevent deletion of parent record.